# Consuming API with authentication from VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, api, authentication

I am trying to consume an API that requires I sign in with a user name and password.

The error I am receiving is

> The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

The Authentication type is Basic.

```
Public Function ForStackOverFlow(requestUri As String)

    Dim response As String

    Dim baseUri = $"http://someapi.example.com/api"
    Dim URI As Uri = New Uri(requestUri)
    Dim credentialCache As New CredentialCache()

    Dim username As String = "username"
    Dim password As String = "password"

    credentialCache.Add(New System.Uri(baseUri), "Basic", New NetworkCredential(username, password))

    Dim request = WebRequest.Create(URI)
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    request.Method = "GET"
    request.Credentials = credentialCache

    Using responseStream = request.GetResponse.GetResponseStream
        Using reader As New StreamReader(responseStream)
            response = reader.ReadToEnd()
        End Using
    End Using

    Return response

End Function
```

Some resources I accessed in trying to solve this problem. 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httprequestheader?view=net-6.0 

[How to consume an asp.net web api in vb.net application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16112200/how-to-consume-an-asp-net-web-api-in-vb-net-application) 

[vb.net Task(Of HttpResponseMessage) to HttpResponseMessage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37995179/vb-net-taskof-httpresponsemessage-to-httpresponsemessage) 

[Value of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task(Of String)' cannot be converted to 'String'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23117055/value-of-type-system-threading-tasks-taskof-string-cannot-be-converted-to-s) 

[SSL TLS 1.2 Channel creation VB.net HTTPS WebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42817334/ssl-tls-1-2-channel-creation-vb-net-https-webrequest) 

[Accept self-signed TLS/SSL certificate in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998004/accept-self-signed-tls-ssl-certificate-in-vb-net) 

[Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40174295/could-not-establish-trust-relationship-for-the-ssl-tls-secure-channel-the-remot)

Comment: What is the API authentication type? JWP? Cookie? basic?

Comment: The Authentication type is Basic, I edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Very few authenticated APIs will allow raw http access. You probably need https://. Very few APIs also use basic authentication. There's almost always some kind of token you need to generate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using `HttpClient` and also `Async/Await`:

e.g

```vb
    Public Async Function ForStackOverFlow(requestUri As String) As Task(Of String)
        Using client As New HttpClient()
            Dim URI As Uri = New Uri(requestUri)
            Dim auth = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username:password1234")
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = New Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(auth))
            Dim response = Await client.GetAsync(URI)
            Dim content = response.Content
            Return Await content.ReadAsStringAsync()
        End Using
    End Function
```

Usage:

```vb
Dim result = Await ForStackOverFlow("http://SomeURL")
' or 
' Dim result = ForStackOverFlow("http://SomeURL").Result
```

Comment: at Dim response = Await client.GetAsync(New Uri(requestUri)) I get Object reference not set to an instance of an object "This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]" I tried to wrap in a try catch but it just enters break mode.

Comment: two questions. 1- what dotnet version are you using? 2- make sure to pass a correct URL.

Comment: 4.7.2. I verified the URL is just like the one that is displayed in swagger when I tested the call I am trying to make.

Comment: I've updated the answer. also tested locally now. this version should work as expected. if didn't, paste the error message

Comment: I tried turning on different exception settings, but all it says is "System.NullReferenceException" Then it says This Exception was originally thrown at this call stack: [External Code]. When I sign in on Swagger it says Authorization Basic, so I would assume we have the auth type correct.

Comment: `System.NullReferenceException` means something is null, try to debug line by line and find the null value.

Comment: I did that, it happens at this line Dim response = Await client.GetAsync(URI)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241741/discussion-between-adam-schneider-and-alireza).

Comment: This was the ticket, thank you.